# script to find given string and replace in all files in given directory

Tags: windows, powershell

How to write script in powershell which finds given string in all files in given directory and changes it to given second one ?

thanks for any help,
bye

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```
    $files = Get-ChildItem "DirectoryContainingFiles"
    foreach ($file in $files) 
    {
    $content = Get-Content -path $file.fullname
    $content | foreach {$_ -replace "toreplace", "replacewith"} | 
Set-Content $file.fullname
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string to replace spans multiple lines then using Get-Content isn't going to cut it unless you stitch together the output of Get-Content into a single string.  It's easier to use [io.file]::ReadAllText() in this case e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | 
    Foreach { $txt = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.fullname); 
              $txt -replace $old,$new; $txt | Out-File $_}
```

Note with with $old, you may need to use a regex directive like '(?s)' at the beginning to indicate that `.` matches newline characters also.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can get the list of all files in a directory (simple?). Now comes the replacement part. Here is how you can do it with power shell:

`type somefile.txt | %{$_ -replace "string_to_be_replaces","new_strings"}`

Modify it as per your need. You can also redirect the output to a new file the same way you do other redirection (using: `>`).

To get the list of files, use:

`Get-ChildItem <DIR_PATH> -name`

Comment: I believe that you can get the list of all files in a directory (simple? -> not really cause I dont use powershell at all but its the only one scripting language I can use in this environment